Does drag coefficient vary with size?
Take three spheres having respectively a 1 meter, 100 meters and 1000 meters diameter. Size aside they don’t differ in any other way.
They’re moving through a fluid at the same, constant velocity of 3 m/s. Pretty much, apologies for the redundancy, the only known feature that changes between them is dimension.
As it’s asked in the title: do these spheres have also varying coefficients of drag?

Have you perused the wikipedia entry on drag coefficients?

I admittedly didn’t. Well, it seems my doubts would have been resolved in a few seconds of read . . . thanks anyway for pointing this out.

According to my knowledge, yes. Because, the drag coefficient is dependent on the mass or the density, cross sectional area and velocity.
$$D=\dfrac{1}{2}C_{\text{D}}\rho V^2 A$$
Thus, the spheres should have varying drag coefficients.
